# Jquery function returning function code not value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return, loops

I am iterating over a list nested within a div (.catHOLDER), finding the img tag and trying to return the img src. The problem I have is that the function is returning all of the function source code instead of the string value, but oddly if I alert in the loop it returns the string value;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getnestedimg() {
    $('.catHOLDER ul').children('li').each(function(i,value) { 
            var imgstr = $(value).find('img').attr('src');
            if (imgstr !== undefined) {
                alert(imgstr);
            }
    });
}
getnestedimg();
});
```

The above code will display an alert with path of the img src, but if I try to return imgstr it returns me the function code instead;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getnestedimg() {
    $('.catHOLDER ul').children('li').each(function(i,value) { 
            var imgstr = $(value).find('img').attr('src');
            if (imgstr !== undefined) {
                return imgstr;
            }
    });
}
getnestedimg();
});
```

Returns the following;

```
function getnestedimg() {
                $('.catHOLDER ul').children('li').each(function(i,value) { 
                    var imgstr = $(value).find('img').attr('src');
                        if (imgstr !== undefined) {
                            //alert(imgstr);
                        //ret urn gotya;
                        return imgstr.val();
                        }
                });
            }
```

Can anyone help me in my plight, or if there is a better way to iterate over the children  tags nested with the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $.fn.extend({
      getsrc : function() {
         return $(this).find(">ul> li img").map(function() {
                   return $(this).attr("src"); 
                   });
             }
    });

   $(document).ready(function() {
        var catHOLDERimgsrc = new Array();
        catHOLDERimgsrc=$(".catHOLDER").getsrc();
        console.log(catHOLDERimgsrc);
   })
```

but a plugin for this ? i would do it direct :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var catHOLDERimgsrc = new Array();
        catHOLDERimgsrc=$(".catHOLDER").find(">ul> li img").map(function() {
                   return $(this).attr("src"); 
                   });
        console.log(catHOLDERimgsrc);
   })
```

imo the nicest way to iterate to get a set of value arranged in an array (that is if you want all the images src otherwise you change selector then if not enough you can do anything inside the map function)

Comment: nb since jq1.9 i think attr is getting deprecated and prop should be favoured; although they mentioned some exceptions

Comment: `attr` is definitely *not* being deprecated. Use of `attr` to get/set properties is what's being deprecated. It's still useful for its intended purpose: getting/setting attributes. Whether the OP wants to get the `src` attribute or the `src` property is an different story altogether...

Comment: Hi Mikakun, I tried the following and it didn't work, it still returned the function code;
   $(document).ready(function(){
    function getnestedimg() {
     var catholderimages=new Array();
        catholderimages=$('.catHOLDER').find('> ul >li > img').map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("src"); 
        });
    }
    alert(getnestedimg);
   });

Comment: no you don't need to make a function of it you just put it in your doc.ready anonymous function & then you get your array catholderimages containing all your src in the same order than the dom - i'll edit answer if you do want a separate function

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement inside the `getnestedimg` function, is acually inside the nested anonymous function you pass to `each`. That's why it's not returning any value to the caller of `getnestedimg`. You should store this value in a function variable of `getnestedimg`, as suggested.

Also, I recommend you read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this:

```
var image_src = $('.catHOLDER ul > li img[src]').first().attr('src');
```

`> li img[src]` selects only `img` tags that have a `src` attribute and are descendants of `li` elements. `.first()` grabs only the first one.

If no elements match those conditions, `image_str === undefined`.

Comment: @JosephSilber: The original code included those as well, but you could exclude them by using `[src!=""]` as the attribute selector.

Comment: Hi Blender, I tried the following, but it sadly didn't work;    $(document).ready(function(){
    function getnestedimg() {
     var image_src = $('.catHOLDER ul > li img[src]').first().attr('src');
     return image_src;
    }
    alert(getnestedimg);
   });